# Como enviar datos que me llegan de la consola en chrome a un input?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, input, socket.io, innerhtml

Quiero visualizar los datos de consola.log() que me llegan automaticamente a chrome en un INPUT
pero al momento de hacerlo no me muestra nada, donde si me muestra datos es en una etiqueta H1
por ejemplo con:

```
   socket. on('temp',function (data){
   console.log(data);
   let temp = document.getElementById('temperature');
   temp.innerHTML = `$(data)`;
```

)

mi html y input tiene la id de temperature

lo que quiero es que me lo muestre en un input ya que con el h1 si funciona
como le puedo hacer para que me muestre los datos en ese input?

Comment: probaste seleccionando el input en js y cambiandole la propiedad value?

Comment: como? lo que quiero hacer solamente es como devolver ese valor "data" a un input como lo hago en el H1 con el id temperature pero creo que es con diferente metodo al innerhtml ya que es un input

Comment: Por eso, el valor actual de un input se encuentra en la propiedad value. Podes cambiarlo como quieras por ejemplo: document.getElementById("mi-input").value = data

Comment: si lo escribi en mi js asi: document.getElementById("temperature").value=data;
y en mi archivo html como: 
<input type="text" id="temperature"> y no me funciono aun

Comment: entonces el problema esta en otro lado, imposible si no tenemos tu codigo.

Comment: En la línea que de "temp.innerHTML = `$(data)`;" no estás haciendo una correcta interpolación de strings. Deberías usar llaves no paréntesis: "temp.innerHTML = `${data}`;"